# Artifactory pro server behind an nginx frontend

Tags: nginx, https, docker, artifactory

I am trying to set up ssl for our artifactory server. For this I wish to configure nginx as the reverse proxy. So far I have done the following

-- Installed artifactory pro using its docker image

```
docker run --name artifactory-registry -p 8081:8081 -v $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/data -v $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/logs  -v $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/backup  -v $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/etc  jfrog-docker-reg2.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-pro:latest
```

-- Insatlled nginx using `sudo apt-get install nginx`

I have the webapp accessible at http://localhost:8081/artifactory/webapp/#/home
and teh following config file under $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/tomcat/conf/server.xml

```
<Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8081"/>

    <!-- This is the optional AJP connector -->
    <Connector port="8019" protocol="AJP/1.3"/>

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
        <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps"/>
    </Engine>

</Service>
```

From sources found online, the following configuration is needed for the nginx to act as a reverse proxy

```
server {
  listen          80;
  server_name     yourdomain.com;
  root            /etc/tomcat7/webapps/apple;

  proxy_cache one;

  location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
  }
}
```

What should be the 'server_name' and 'root' in this path? Also how do I test the reverse proxiness of this setup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually you will configure SSL on it's default HTTPs port (443).
Take a look at [this page](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/nginx) for configuring nginx with SSL.

The `server_name` is the host from which you will connect to your nginx (from the browser for example). Usually you will have a DNS address from your company (like `artifactory.mycompany.com`) and you will use that, but if everything is local you can just put `localhost` instead. 
Here is a working SSL configuration on port 443:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name artifactory.mycompany.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/artifactory.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/artifactory.error.log;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/artifactory.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/artifactory.key;

    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location /artifactory {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_read_timeout 90;
    }
}
```

Simply put your SSL certificates at the configured locations and you are good to go.

Connecting to https://artifactory.mycompany.com from your browser should now work (or https://localhost if you used that for `server_name`).

Comment: Hi @shayy why is the location /artifactory and not just /